# Set colour of a Polyline in Google Maps v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I set the colour of a Google Maps Polyline?

```
var myRoutePath;
myRoutePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: routeCoordinates,
  strokeColor: "#CC33FF",
  strokeWeight: 3
});     
myRoutePath.setMap(map);
// Reset colour
myRoutePath.setOptions({strokeColor: 'blue'});
```

The above doesn't show up as an error in Firebug, but it doesn't change the color either.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Basically looks correct to me. However, if this is your code verbatim then you immediately overwrite the color. Hence, I guess you are getting a blue polyline from the start. Try setting a timer to see the transition:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    myRoutePath.setOptions({strokeColor: 'blue'});
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Color names are still not supported as a color, use the hex version instead

```
myRoutePath.setOptions({strokeColor: '#0000FF'});
```

Comment: As of April 2019 color names work for polyline colors